# Can we convert momentum to coulombs in any simple sense?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, momentum, charge

Let's suppose hypothetically you throw a specially shaped magnet designed with sliding plates, and when it hits the ground it converts almost all it's momentum, or if need be for more complications, kinetic energy into some type of electrical discharge.

How do I quantify this electrical discharge? What unit is appropriate? Is coulombs appropriate? Is there a theoretical maximum on how much of an objects kinetic motion can ever be converted?

Answer (score 1):

Charge and momentum are separately conserved. So you cannot convert one into the other.

However, in [geometrized units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system), charge and momentum both have dimensions of length. So in that unit system they are dimensionally equivalent even if they cannot be converted into each other. In the geometrized system $1 \mathrm{\ m}= 3.274 \ 10^{16} \mathrm{\ C}$ and $1 \mathrm{\ m}=4.037 \ 10^{35} \mathrm{\ kg \ m/s}$ so $1 \mathrm{\ C} = 1.233 \ 10^{19} \mathrm{\ kg \ m/s}$.

But again, even though in the geometrized system those quantities are equivalent they cannot be converted into each other because they are separately conserved.

Comment: Okay, well then momentum is insufficient information, how about energy? Energy is force over a distance and you generate current by applying the force of a magnetic field over a distance. Electricity is often taken to be "electrical" energy. Is there a way to convert energy into an electrically derived unit?

Comment: Energy is also conserved separately from either charge or momentum

Comment: What I mean is, suppose we know the kinetic energy in joules instead, and all that energy gets converted into moving magnets over a distance that generates electricity. That electricity is some type of unit of electrical energy that brings electrons to a higher energy level and causes some number of charges to move short distances to transfer that energy from one electron to the next, or generates additional charges in some way. Is there a way I could calculate voltage or amperes from energy and the mass of the object? Or what additional information would be needed?

Comment: Energy is conserved so you could convert 1 J of kinetic energy into 1 J of electromagnetic energy. Not voltage or current or charge or momentum. Energy just converts to other forms of energy.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a magnet through a solenoid coil attached to some electrical load or battery could, in principle, halt the magnet's motion and transfer that into electrical energy. This is, in fact, a disorganized version of what every power plant does (except solar panels).     And like the energy from a power plant,  it can be converted to virtually any voltage or current via transformers (from 10,000 V power lines that can cause arcs in air, down to a low voltage home appliance).  To find these possible values, equate the kinetic energy with electrical energy

$$E_k=E_e$$
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2=Vq$$

Where $V$ is your voltage and $q$ your charge accumulated (in a generic battery). Or using a capacitor, the right side would be $1/2V^2C$ where $C$ is the capacitance.